# Bad Process When Creating Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger in my phpmyadmin but I get an error

when I run this query in the SQL terminal it works fine. but in the trigger creation, I get the bad processes error and the query has failed.

```
set @sql = CONCAT(
    "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/database/",DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%Y'),
    ".csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n ' FROM weekevents"
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: This looks unclear to me... What is the relation between the trigger that you say you want to create and the piece of code you showed, that exports data from database into a CSV file ?

Comment: when I update the table I want new CSV file will be created, I really don't know why in the trigger creation I get the error

Comment: OK. You would need to show us the entire trigger code, along with the exact error message that you are getting.

Comment: in my post, this is the entire trigger code, the error messeg is : One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:</b> <ul> <li>The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Exsport Insert` AFTER INSERT ON `weekevents` FOR EACH ROW set @sql = concat("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/database/",DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%Y'),".csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n ' FROM weekevents");

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;"<br>MySQL said

Comment: when I remove the PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; the trigger is ok but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, dynamic SQL is not allowed in triggers.

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) :

> SQL prepared statements (`PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, **stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL** (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).

You should actually be getting error :

> #1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: thank you but when i place your code i still get the same error. when i add : PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; i get the failed error,  without it I can add a trigger but nothing happens

Comment: @drorshalit : I changed my answer... Have a look !

Comment: hmmm i see... any idea how can i make it work? how to export csv on update?

Comment: @drorshalit : you can export to CSV using a regular SQL statement : this will give you a constant file name. You would need to rename the file outside of MySQL.